# Filter output with ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

So I'm connecting with ansible to an interconnect device running PicOS8. I'm issuing a command which has the following output:

```
10.240.18.20,fe80::a94:efff:fe50:b516%eth0
fe80::a94:efff:fe71:d996%vlan.4,10.240.23.34
fe80::a94:efff:fe71:daa6%vlan.4,10.240.23.
```

This is not always standard since sometimes, the ipv4 address preceeds the ipv6 or at times there is no ipv6 at all.

I'm registering this output using ansible **register**, let's say as **smm_output**.

Then I want to display the output, showing only the ipv4 ip addresses (with the playbook bellow):

```
   - debug:
       msg: "{{ smm_output.stdout_lines | ipv4('address') }}"
```

but the output is blank. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here or how to strictly show the ipv4 ip addresses from that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to traverse the list `stdout_lines` and split the string to the list. Try this one:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.split(',') | ipv4('address') }}"
  loop: "{{smm_output.stdout_lines}}"
```

You can also create separate array with IPv4 only

```
- set_fact:
    ip4: []

- set_fact:
    ip4: "{{ ip4 + (item.split(',') | ipv4('address') )}}"
  loop: "{{smm_output.stdout_lines}}"

- debug:
    var: ip4
```

Which should generate below output:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "ip4": [
        "10.240.18.20",
        "10.240.23.34"
    ]
}
```

Comment: So I'm using as you suggested. The output is this: `TASK [debug]
ok: [10.240.18.57] => {
    "msg": [
        "  fe80::a94:efff:fe50:b516%eth0,10.240.18.20",
        "fe80::a94:efff:fe71:d996%vlan.4,10.240.23.34",
        "fe80::a94:efff:fe71:daa6%vlan.4,10.240.23.35"
    ]
}

TASK [debug]
ok: [10.240.18.57] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": [
        "10.240.18.20"
    ]
}
ok: [10.240.18.57] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": [
        "10.240.23.34"
    ]
}
ok: [10.240.18.57] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": [
        "10.240.23.35"
    ]
}` how do I get rid of that item=None?

Comment: Sorry not sure how to format the text right inside a comment

Comment: can you send me the output of below task `- debug: msg="{{ smm_output.stdout_lines }}"`

Comment: `ok: [10.240.18.57] => {
    "msg": [
        "fe80::a94:efff:fe50:b516%eth0,10.240.18.20",
        "fe80::a94:efff:fe71:d996%vlan.4,10.240.23.34",
        "fe80::a94:efff:fe71:daa6%vlan.4,10.240.23.35"
    ]
}`

Comment: Weird, I have ```ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=10.240.18.20,fe80::a94:efff:fe50:b516%eth0) => {
    "msg": [
        "10.240.18.20"
    ]
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=fe80::a94:efff:fe71:d996%vlan.4,10.240.23.34) => {
    "msg": [
        "10.240.23.34"
    ]
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=fe80::a94:efff:fe71:daa6%vlan.4,10.240.23.) => {
    "msg": []
}
```

Comment: I'll check it later. Thank you very much!